# How can I modify a home standing fan to run at low RPM?

Tags: motor, ac

I have a house standing fan 220V AC. I need to do modification to make it run on 15 RPM (revolutions per minute), usually fan runs higher RPM than that.

Is there a way to make my fan run around 15 RPM? I know if I connect it to a dimmer that will create a problem and the motor will become hot! But I heard if I connect it in series a light bulb that may make its RPM lower.

Please, can anyone suggest something?

Comment: No, the type of motor involved simply cannot do that.  Attempting to make it happen will lead to anywhere between no movement or starting a fire.

Comment: Use a gearbox..

Comment: is there any other idea than a gear box ? because I need the blades and dimensions of the fan as they are. I dont want to modify the motor moun.

Comment: No. 15RPM is far too slow compared to the speed the fan was designed to run at to achieve through electrical, especially simple, electrical means. It's about a hundred times slower than what it was meant to run at. It's like trying to make a car engine run slower by barely giving it any gas. It will barely have any torque and just stall.

Comment: ok fine. what type of motor should i use for this ? It came in my mind to use car windshield wiper motor, but the problem it runs on 5 or 12 volts dc ( 5 amps) and i dont know how to connect it to 220 volts AC. do you have any idea of other motors that can do this ?

Comment: @yanal, What about a ceiling fan?  Some of those can go pretty slow.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Your original question has been answered in comments i.e. "you can't" (or use a gearbox). Your first new question is fundamentally different i.e. how do I connect a windshield motor to 220 VAC. Then you have another new question asking for shopping recommendations and they are off-topic. Nobody is going to make an answer for your new questions based on the body of your original question. Well "nobody" might be a bit presumptive. Somebody might who is really keen to help.

Comment: Look for a 15 rpm timing motor.  You'll need to know your line frequency (probably 50 Hz if 220 volts, but do check).  Or go a bit faster and use a rubber drive belt to reduce to 15 rpm.

Comment: Chris Stratton thanks a lot, you gave me a nice idea, I will use a rubber drive along with the house fan to do the trick . thanks a lot people for the answers :)

Comment: @yanal you should be very careful at every step of the way. Slow motors tend to draw a lot of current which will rapidly heat up the wires, burn the insulation, cause a short, and spark a fire very quickly.

Comment: techSultan I will try to make the motor load as low as possible ( by choosing thin belt and not tightening the pulleys too much. Thanks a lot Sultan :)